# Add non-existing column to view

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

Is it possible to add a SERIAL column to an existing view if that field does not exist in the source table? I want to get an autoincremental ID field named OID that cannot be NULL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.osm_polygon AS 

SELECT planet_osm_polygon.osm_id::text AS osm_id, 
    planet_osm_polygon.tags -> 'osm_timestamp'::text AS osm_timestamp, 
    planet_osm_polygon.tags -> 'name:en'::text AS name_en, 
    planet_osm_polygon.access, planet_osm_polygon.admin_level, 
    planet_osm_polygon.aerialway, planet_osm_polygon.aeroway, 
    planet_osm_polygon.amenity, planet_osm_polygon.area, 
    planet_osm_polygon.barrier, planet_osm_polygon.bicycle, 
    planet_osm_polygon.brand, planet_osm_polygon.bridge, way
    planet_osm_polygon.boundary, planet_osm_polygon.building FROM planet_osm_polygon
WHERE st_isvalid(planet_osm_polygon.way) AND planet_osm_polygon.way && st_makeenvelope((-17.5)::double precision, 3.0::double precision, 8.7::double precision, 26.9::double precision, 4326);
```

So that is my view.

I need to add a column that contains an auto-incremental field as Long Integers or Serial that cannot be NULL. Any suggestions?

Comment: What about using `row_number()`? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: Add the column in the underlying tables(s) and then include it in the `VIEW` definition.

Comment: Don't call the column it `OID`, though. That's typically used as the "object identifier" internally and is treated specially. Don't confuse things.

Answer (score 1):

Using [row_number](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.osm_polygon AS 

SELECT planet_osm_polygon.osm_id::text AS osm_id, 
planet_osm_polygon.tags -> 'osm_timestamp'::text AS osm_timestamp, 
planet_osm_polygon.tags -> 'name:en'::text AS name_en, 
planet_osm_polygon.access, planet_osm_polygon.admin_level, 
planet_osm_polygon.aerialway, planet_osm_polygon.aeroway, 
planet_osm_polygon.amenity, planet_osm_polygon.area, 
planet_osm_polygon.barrier, planet_osm_polygon.bicycle, 
planet_osm_polygon.brand, planet_osm_polygon.bridge, way,
planet_osm_polygon.boundary, planet_osm_polygon.building,
row_number() over() as row_num
 FROM planet_osm_polygon
WHERE st_isvalid(planet_osm_polygon.way) AND planet_osm_polygon.way && st_makeenvelope((-17.5)::double precision, 3.0::double precision, 8.7::double precision, 26.9::double precision, 4326);
```

Comment: You should add some kind of ordering to `row_number()`. Maybe `order by planet_osm_polygon.osm_id`? Otherwise it can return different results for different executions.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: in general I agree with you that `row_number()` only makes sense with an `order by`. But the numbers generated in the view won't be stable anyway. Just think about rows being deleted or inserted in the underlying table (the real question is: is `row_number()` good enough for josh?)